# Convert number From Excel cell to IEEE 754 Hex format

Tags: excel, floating-point, ieee-754, floating-point-conversion

Recently I have been wrestling with Excel due to the 15 significant digits display limit for a number. I have been looking for a way to display the IEEE 754 format of a value contained in a Excel cell (*since they are [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result) to work that way*).

I'd prefer **not** to rely on VBA for this project (*although I might get tempted if a `memcpy`-like solution is possible*).

See my answer below for my current implementation. Any input or alternative is appreciated. I choose to believe that I missed an easier, well-tested solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following sequence allow me to convert a number to its IEEE 754 hexadecimal representation using Excel formulas.
I did not try to handle any exceptions besides 0. From Cell A1 to G1:

- A1: `0.123456`
- B1: `=INT(LOG(ABS(A1),2))` Exponent
- C1: `=ABS(A1)/(2^B1)`Mantissa
- D1: `=(C1-1)*(2^52)` Convert mantissa to decimal
- E1: `=DEC2HEX(1023+B1+IF(A1<0,2^11,0),3)` Convert sign & exponent to hex
- F1: `=CONCATENATE(DEC2HEX(D1/2^32,5),DEC2HEX(MOD(D1,2^32),8))` Convert decimal to hex.
- G1: `="0x"&IF(A1=0,0,E1&F1)`

A few of my result:

- 22222.0948199999 > 0x40D5B3861187E7A5
- `=1.35632902954101*2^14` > 0x40D5B3861187E7A7
- [22222.09482](https://superuser.com/questions/1367025/in-excel-when-i-enter-22222-09482-then-i-see-22222-0948199999-number-in-the-for) > 0x40D5B3861187E7C0
- 0.000123456 > 0x3F202E7EF70994DD
- 1E+307 > 0x7FAC7B1F3CAC7433
- -35.3 > 0xC041A66666666666
- 1 > 0x3FF0000000000000

***EDIT**: Follow-up to chux comments.*

We can see that the following value give a wrong result due to a rounding error:

- `=255+0.9999999999999` > 0x40700000FFFFFFFE

Under this scenario, the value given at the step D1 is negative. If I use this information to update my exponent, my results appear to be consistent:

- `=255+0.9999999999999` > 0x406FFFFFFFFFFFFC

Here is the updated B1 formula:

- B1: `=IF((ABS(A1)/(2^INT(LOG(ABS(A1),2)))-1)*(2^52)<0,INT(LOG(ABS(A1),2))-1,INT(LOG(ABS(A1),2)))`

***EDIT2**: above steps in a single function using LET (Available in Microsoft 365)*

```
=LET(num,A1,
exp,INT(LOG(ABS(num),2)),
exponent,IF((ABS(num)/(2^exp)-1)*(2^52)<0,exp-1,exp),
mantissa,(ABS(num)/(2^exponent)-1)*(2^52),
part_a,DEC2HEX(1023+exponent+IF(num<0,2^11,0),3),
part_b,CONCATENATE(DEC2HEX(mantissa/2^32,5),DEC2HEX(MOD(mantissa,2^32),8)),
"0x"&IF(num=0,0,part_a&part_b))
```

**EDIT3**: as the point was already raised twice, I am adding a "most likely correct" answer for 32-bit float format.

```
=LET(num,A1,
exp,INT(LOG(ABS(num),2)),
exponent,IF((ABS(num)/(2^exp)-1)*(2^23)<0,exp-1,exp),
base_mantissa,(ABS(num)/(2^exponent)-1)*(2^23),
round_nearest_tie_even,IF(base_mantissa-INT(base_mantissa)=0.5,EVEN(base_mantissa),ROUND(base_mantissa,0)),
"0x"&IF(num=0,0,DEC2HEX((127+exponent+IF(num<0,2^8,0))*(2^23)+round_nearest_tie_even,8)))
```

This was less straightforward than expected:

- My 64-bit answer relies on a trick to work with DEC2HEX 40-bit limit. It is unecessary (*and does not work*) with 32-bit.
- The mantissa had to be rounded, I had to check the [documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Rounding_rules) against Excel's [ROUND](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/round-a-number-f82b440b-689d-4221-b21e-38da99d33435#:%7E:text=The%20ROUND%20function%20rounds%20a,the%20number%20is%20rounded%20down.). **The round part of my equation has not been tested thoroughly**: test cases exists but I don't know how much time it would take me to find them.

Comment: This is how a self-answer should be done. Nice work

Comment: For me, fails for values near 1 like `0.999999999999999`.  Can you generate `0x3FEFFFFFFFFFFFFF`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I managed to generate `0x3FEFFFFFFFFFFFFF` with `=0.0099999999999999+0.99`

Comment: With values near a power of 2,  I see `INT(LOG(ABS(A1);2))` having insufficient precision.  Between two powers of 2, there are 2^52 different `double`, yet the reported log2 of `A1` will be a rounded result.  Say `128 <= A1 < 256.0`, the log is  [7.0 ... 8.0), there are not 2^52 different `double` and `A1` values near 256 will round to 8.  Thus leading to the wrong hex format.  Perhaps with a 2-stage determination of the _Exponent_, a rough and then a refined one.  Hmmmm.

Comment: This converts to 64 bit – double could someone share formula that converts to 32 Bit - Float?

Comment: @RomanToasov Though it goes beyond my original question, I have edited my answer with a 32 bits-float solution.

Answer (score -1):

Please use following expression to convert into 32 bit hex in little endian format. Put float value in cell A1 or change the below expression

> =(
> (RIGHT("00"&BIN2HEX((IF(IF(A1<0,-1,1)=1,0,1))&LEFT((RIGHT("00000000"&DEC2BIN(IF(ABS(A1)<1.1754943E-38,-127,INT(LOG(ABS(A1))/LOG(2)))+127),8)),7)),2))
> &
> (RIGHT("00"&BIN2HEX(RIGHT((RIGHT("00000000"&DEC2BIN(IF(ABS(A1)<1.1754943E-38,-127,INT(LOG(ABS(A1))/LOG(2)))+127),8)),1)&(RIGHT("0000000"&DEC2BIN(INT(INT((IF(IF(ABS(A1)<1.1754943E-38,-127,INT(LOG(ABS(A1))/LOG(2)))+127=0,ROUND((A1/2^(IF(ABS(A1)<1.1754943E-38,-127,INT(LOG(ABS(A1))/LOG(2))))/(IF(A1<0,-1,1)))*4194304,0),ROUND(((A1/2^(IF(ABS(A1)<1.1754943E-38,-127,INT(LOG(ABS(A1))/LOG(2))))/(IF(A1<0,-1,1)))-1)*(8388608),0)))/256)/256)),7))),2))
> &
> (RIGHT("00"&BIN2HEX(RIGHT("00000000"&DEC2BIN(((INT((IF(IF(ABS(A1)<1.1754943E-38,-127,INT(LOG(ABS(A1))/LOG(2)))+127=0,ROUND((A1/2^(IF(ABS(A1)<1.1754943E-38,-127,INT(LOG(ABS(A1))/LOG(2))))/(IF(A1<0,-1,1)))*4194304,0),ROUND(((A1/2^(IF(ABS(A1)<1.1754943E-38,-127,INT(LOG(ABS(A1))/LOG(2))))/(IF(A1<0,-1,1)))-1)*(8388608),0)))/256)/256)-INT(INT((IF(IF(ABS(A1)<1.1754943E-38,-127,INT(LOG(ABS(A1))/LOG(2)))+127=0,ROUND((A1/2^(IF(ABS(A1)<1.1754943E-38,-127,INT(LOG(ABS(A1))/LOG(2))))/(IF(A1<0,-1,1)))*4194304,0),ROUND(((A1/2^(IF(ABS(A1)<1.1754943E-38,-127,INT(LOG(ABS(A1))/LOG(2))))/(IF(A1<0,-1,1)))-1)*(8388608),0)))/256)/256))*256),8)),2))
> &
> (RIGHT("00"&BIN2HEX(RIGHT("00000000"&DEC2BIN((((IF(IF(ABS(A1)<1.1754943E-38,-127,INT(LOG(ABS(A1))/LOG(2)))+127=0,ROUND((A1/2^(IF(ABS(A1)<1.1754943E-38,-127,INT(LOG(ABS(A1))/LOG(2))))/(IF(A1<0,-1,1)))*4194304,0),ROUND(((A1/2^(IF(ABS(A1)<1.1754943E-38,-127,INT(LOG(ABS(A1))/LOG(2))))/(IF(A1<0,-1,1)))-1)*(8388608),0)))/256)-(INT((IF(IF(ABS(A1)<1.1754943E-38,-127,INT(LOG(ABS(A1))/LOG(2)))+127=0,ROUND((A1/2^(IF(ABS(A1)<1.1754943E-38,-127,INT(LOG(ABS(A1))/LOG(2))))/(IF(A1<0,-1,1)))*4194304,0),ROUND(((A1/2^(IF(ABS(A1)<1.1754943E-38,-127,INT(LOG(ABS(A1))/LOG(2))))/(IF(A1<0,-1,1)))-1)*(8388608),0)))/256)))*256),8)),2))
> )

Tested and working

Comment: It is now possible with Microsoft 365 to transform my original answer into a single function using LET without compromising readibility too much. As for your answer, it appears to be shown incorrectly, most likely because `*` is interpreted as text format.